# Django sessions with Oauth - cannot pass variables thru request.session

Tags: python, django, session, oauth

I am building an app for making API calls to websites like (FB, LinkedIn, etc.) I need to use OAuth to authorize my application to request data on behalf of the user. I am stuck with a problem of storing the instance of my website interface library (LinkedIn) across views. I used request.session - with file back end.

Below is the code http://pastebin.com/QTgqSr7W

Am I doing something wrong?  can see the value being set in login() but I cannot see the same value in token(). Is this wrong to expect? Any workaround for passing the value of the api instance?

Thanks and Regards,
Atul.

Comment: request.session should save the data when you add something to to "dictionary", but to force a save you can assign request.session.modified = True after assigning request.session['api_obj'] in your login() def.

Comment: I tried that, it did not help. It is as if I am loosing the old session and this is a new session.

Comment: I observed something here while debugging, the _session_key is populated earlier with one value [0eb3788d6bb409021e8d83451a9d81a9] in login() view but in the token() view it is different [7128c6f9bdb347c2e4b010822b3d38a9], I guess this is the culprit, but then how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmm, i think its because you are saving the entire api python instance, i dont think that sessions support that kind of data, why not just redirect user to auth url without saving something in session, then in callback view, you instantiate the `linkedin.LinkedIn` class like so

```
from django.conf import settings

key = settings.KEY
secret = settings.SECRET
return_url = settings.CALLBACK


# You make the api connection here, so its not tied to any function
api = linkedin.LinkedIn(key, secret, return_url)

def login(request):
    if api.request_token():
        auth_url = api.get_authorize_url()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(auth_url)

#below is the view that will get called with the oauth oken.
def token(request, param):
    #do stuff with the api.
```

Comment: I tried that, it did not work. I need to call api.request_token() before I can get the access token.

Comment: its calling api.request_token(), and then redirects the user to auth_url, please specify if thats not the intended behavior

Comment: yes but when I loose the state of the api object in the next views it needs to call request_token() again to populate _request_token and _request_token_secret variables. I tried setting these string values in my session, that did not work either. May be I am doing something wrong with Sessions.

Comment: I observed something here while debugging, the _session_key is populated earlier with one value [0eb3788d6bb409021e8d83451a9d81a9] in login() view but in the token() view it is different [7128c6f9bdb347c2e4b010822b3d38a9], I guess this is the culprit, but then how do I fix this?

Comment: ohh, now i see your problem, i was experiencing the same thing, ill edit my answer to include the code i used to solve the issue :D

Comment: ok so that worked and I will mark this response as answer, but isn't it against the Object Oriented programming principles? I would certainly like to see a more cleaner approach but for this will do for me.